# Changing size of crystal report print image runtime

Tags: crystal-reports

I am new to .net application. Here i am generating the crystal report in my application. My problem is that i want to change the size of crystal report print image. How can i customize the size of print image in crystal report.I have used jquery to change the size of print button on run time. I got succesfull in changing the size but when i clicked on print button nothing happens. Please give me some suggestion to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved the above question by myself using jquery, so if you have same question as mine than see the following code:

$(document).ready(function() {
                $(".crtoolbar input:image").each(function() {
                    $(this).attr("style", "width:32px");
                });
            });